# How to save image in Android using EffectFactory with OpenGL ES 2

Tags: android, image, opengl-es

https://github.com/Averus89/GLEditor/tree/master/GL%20Editor/src/main/java/com/epstim/gleditor/gleditor

Here are source files for my project. I have problem with saving texture data to Image files. There is solution to get pixels from GLES20 but I'll get whole Viewport not only texture with applied filter. Another concern: my picture have over 2,5k pixels width and 1,9k pixels height. Do the result will have same dimensions or gonna have less pixels?